# How to call function of a parent from child and do not update the parent state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

In React 16.X, I have function in my parent component:

```jsx
const fetchData = ()=> {
  return ajax
     .get({},data)
     .then((response) =>
       {
         setState(response);
         // Here I update the state with setState()
       })
     .catch((error) =>
       {
       });
};
```

Now I pass this inside my child in `props`:

```jsx
<child fetchData={fetchData}/>
```

In my child I go with:

```jsx
const {fetchData} = props;

// from my parent
```

But when I call this `fetchData` from my child, it updates the state of my parent (because of the `setState`). All I wanted was to reuse the `fetchData` function to get data from the API, not change the state of the parent.

Is there a possible way to achieve this? I want to reuse the function `fetchData` but not update the parent state.

Comment: Instead of making the `setState` command a part of the function, limit the function to the request itself (i.e. let it return just the ajax.get call). Then use `props.fetchData().then(response => ...)` in the child component. Alternatively, pass the correct `setState` method to `fetchData` as parameter.

Comment: i understand this is a very basic solution but in case where project grows into huge files is there other way to achieve this? @ChrisG

Comment: Well, it's a very basic problem, too :) Not sure I understand why project size would matter; my solution creates a generic function to get data which makes it perfectly suitable for a big project. Not sure what other solution you imagine here?

Comment: Ok i understand could be me taking things very hardly. Ok i will look upto the changes you suggested and try this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are stuck with this:

Please use the following to get through:

```
//define a function that only returns the request

const request = () =>{
    return ajax
           .get({},data);
};

//In anywhere else use it like this in main function

const fetchData = async ()=> {
    const request = this.request();

    return request
    .then((response) =>
        {
            setState(response);
            // Here I update the state with setState()
        })
        .catch((error) =>
        {
        });
};

//Or pass it in the props to use in the child component as
//In parent
<Abc requestFunc={this.request}/>

//and in Abc Component

const abc= (props)=>{
    const requestCall = {props}
}

//call requestCall

requestCall().then....
```